# React Native Issue while setting up new Project macOs

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 669ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

> > But it was running perfectly on ios simulator only problem while running or android emulator

Comment: Found the solution: It works for me

In gradle-wrapper.properties I changed the distributionUrl 
>> previous :   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip
>> change to : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

Comment: Please let as now what version of `react-native` are you using, so that other users with same version can easier find the solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**In gradle-wrapper.properties**
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip